# Elegant way of exposing ItemContainerGenerator in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What's the elegant way of exposing `ItemContainerGenerator` from custom control?

I have `ItemsSource` property on my custom control and I would like to access `UIElement` corresponding to the bound item outside of it.

I don't have access to the `ItemsControl` nor `ItemsContainerGenerator` outside of my control. Should I expose `ItemsControl` or `ItemContainerGenerator` as a property, or maybe add a method for retrieving the `UIElement`?

I need to show the popup near the selected item. Maybe the popup should be a part of the control then I wouldn't have to do this?

Comment: The built-in `ItemsControl` class has an `ItemContainerGenerator` property.

Comment: Imho, you should make your popup a part of the control, because you can get `UIElement` using `ContainerFromItem` method from `ItemsContainerGenerator`. In your case you should expose it to outside

Comment: @mm8 yes, in my situation I have multiple (aggregate) `ItemsControl` in my custom control acting like one.

Comment: So why do you need to expose an `ItemContainerGenerator`? I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: @mm8 so I could access item containers outside of custom control. Maybe deriving my control from `ItemsControl` or `Selector` would be a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to access the entire child `ItemsControl`, create a public read-only property that returns it.

If you only want to expose the `ItemContainerGenerator`, create a read-only property that returns it, e.g.:

```
public ChildItemContainerGenerator => childControl.ItemContainerGenerator;
```

If it makes no sense to expose the entire `ItemContainerGenerator`, create a public method that uses the `ItemContainerGenerator` internally to perform whatever you want to.

Which option to choose all comes down to your requirements actually.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably create a public method and/or pass `UIElement` in my routed event args. I think there's no other way around it.